# UML - Representing wait and continue with the actions

Tags: uml, visio, sequence-diagram, rational-rose

I am new to UML and trying to draw a sequence diagram for one of our functionality.
I am using Microsoft Visio to draw the UML.

I have to represent an option where user has Skip, Pause and Proceed options.

Skip -  loop has to break there

Pause - Wait for the defined duration and continue from there.

Proceed - Should continue with defined actions

Would I be able to represent the above scenario using 'Alt' fragment? If yes, how can I represent the 'Break'?

And how can I represent 'PAUSE' and continue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use not 'alt' combined fragment, but the 'loop' one. Inside it you draw the logic for continuation or breaking.